# My hard drive running out of space using temp tables in MySQL SSMS, what can I do to continue with my work?

Tags: mysql

My computer only has 5.5 GB of available disk space.

I am running heavy queries that are computing billions of records with many temporary tables to get the final output. What's clogging my hard drive is not the final output but the temporary tables generated during the query.

I know the following can help to workaround the issue:

- Shrink database
- Improve query efficiency (which I had with many indexes, etc...)

While the above list helps, I am going to need something more effective than this as I plan to have much more vast computation that will require space from the hard drive that realistically my computer won't be able to accommodate the space for it no matter if I shrink or how much I improve the query efficiency.

So the question is, what can I do to accrue for this extra space, would an external hard drive work? Could I use a cloud computer, or do I need to buy a whole new computer with more space in the hard drive to get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @halfer, the size of the temp file is approximately 45 GB. I don't want to remove more files from my PC as I've done that extensively.

Comment: An external NVMe drive over USB3.1 can be very quick, and it's worth considering if internal storage is not an option.

Comment: One trivial option worth trying is to get yourself a shared LAMP hosting account (based on cPanel or similar). They are usually a few dollars/pounds/euros per month. Get one that has sufficient disk space and upload your data - assuming the database is 10s of Gigabytes of data, you'll need a fast connection. Then try re-running your queries. The advantage here is that often the database server is underused, and often the machine will have a large amount of RAM (e.g. 64G). That will mean your queries will fully or mostly run without disk writing.

Comment: The database I used for my project. and that database size alone, is 223.88MB, it says in the properties also that there is only 46.27MB Space Available

Comment: An alternative to a shared hosting account is AWS RDS - you pay as you go. It'll be rather more expensive, but it will be much more scalable. Uploading 223G of data is not a nice task, but is achievable if you have a good connection.

Comment: Do you really use MySQL? SSMS is SQL Server (MS SQL) client and does not deal with MySQL...

Comment: Pick one of the queries, provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The solution may involve [summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .